# How did watsapp keep an image in the url?

Tags: urls, google

[image]

See the globe picture? I could not find an answer in any website as to how they pulled this off. Any clue?

Comment: How is this related to User Experience?

Comment: What you are asking is related to Implementation rather than User-Experience.

Answer (score 1):

That is a unicode character, *many, but not all* of which are allowed in URLs.

is U+1F310

They could also have put

U+1F30E
U+1F30D
U+1F30F

or any other unicode character in their URLs.

Lots of detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

Comment: Only `U+1F30F` actually shows for me.